# Mixed instance and static synchronized method, get unexpected testing output

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

To my knowledge, in java, a static synchronized & a instance synchronized method won't effect each other's execution, since they lock on different object (`this` instance vs the `class` object itself).

In following code there are 2 sub threads, one runs a instance synchronized method, the other runs a static synchronized method.

Since `++` operator is not atomic, I am expecting following test case to pass *(the final count should be less than the time `++` called)*, but it always fail the test *(the final count equals to the time `++` called)*.

**SyncInstanceAndStaticRelationshipLearn.java**

```
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

/**
 * Relationship of instance & static synchronized method.
 *
 * @author eric
 * @date 1/3/19 9:32 PM
 */
public class SyncInstanceAndStaticRelationshipLearn {
    private static final int ROUND = 1000;
    private static final int INC_THREAD_COUNT = 2;
    private static final long OPTIONAL_INC_DELAY = 1; // optional increase delay,
    private static int N = 0;

    @Test
    public void test() throws InterruptedException {
        ThreadGroup tg = new ThreadGroup("runner");

        new Thread(tg, () -> {
            try {
                new MixedCounter().batchInsSync();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }, "ts-inst").start();

        new Thread(tg, () -> {
            try {
                MixedCounter.batchStaticSync();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }, "ts-static").start();

        Thread[] tArr = new Thread[INC_THREAD_COUNT];
        tg.enumerate(tArr); // get threads,

        // wait all runner to finish,
        for (Thread t : tArr) {
            t.join();
        }

        System.out.printf("\nfinal count: %d\n", getN());
        // just check the output, and can see the instance & static methods mixed,
        Assert.assertTrue(getN() < INC_THREAD_COUNT * ROUND);
    }

    public static int getN() {
        return N;
    }

    // increase & print,
    private static void incAndPrint() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.printf("[%s] start, N: %d\n", Thread.currentThread().getName(), getN());
        N++;
        Thread.sleep(OPTIONAL_INC_DELAY);
        System.out.printf("[%s] end, N: %d\n", Thread.currentThread().getName(), getN());
    }

    // batch increase & print,
    private static void batchInsAndPrint() throws InterruptedException {
        for (int i = 0; i < ROUND; i++) {
            incAndPrint();
        }
    }

    // mixed instance / static counter,
    static class MixedCounter {
        public synchronized void batchInsSync() throws InterruptedException {
            batchInsAndPrint();
        }

        public synchronized static void batchStaticSync() throws InterruptedException {
            batchInsAndPrint();
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Output

```
[ts-inst] start, N: 0
[ts-static] start, N: 0
[ts-inst] end, N: 1
[ts-inst] start, N: 2
[ts-inst] end, N: 3
[ts-inst] start, N: 3
[ts-static] end, N: 2
[ts-inst] end, N: 4
[ts-inst] start, N: 4
[ts-inst] end, N: 5
[ts-inst] start, N: 5
[ts-inst] end, N: 6
[ts-inst] start, N: 6
[ts-inst] end, N: 7
[ts-inst] start, N: 7
[ts-inst] end, N: 8
[ts-inst] start, N: 8
[ts-static] start, N: 4
[ts-inst] end, N: 9
[ts-inst] start, N: 10
[ts-inst] end, N: 11
[ts-inst] start, N: 11
[ts-static] end, N: 10
...
[ts-inst] start, N: 1999
[ts-inst] end, N: 2000

final count: 2000

java.lang.AssertionError: expected [true] but found [false]
Expected :true
Actual   :false
```

From the output, you can see that the 2 threads indeed mixed, but the final count is not less, even after increase the `ROUND` to 1 million, it's still the same.

So, which part am I getting wrong?

Comment: Why do you expect it to always be less than the number of executions?

Comment: incAndPrint() doesn't synchronize on N, the value displayed when printing the "start" is not guaranted to be the same as the one used in the `N++` line

Comment: @jhamon Since the number `N` is increased by operator `++`, there are 2 threads doing that, and `++` is not atomic, so it should be less with enough threads & `++` operation. If the instance & static lock don't effect each other, then this program should be equal to no `synchronized` keywords exists at all, that's what I thought now.

Comment: Your logic is flawed. It's not safe to cross the street with your eyes closed. That doesn't mean that you're guaranteed to get hit by a car if you do it. You might try it a thousand times and never get hit. That doesn't mean it's safe. It just means you got lucky.

Comment: @EricWang I see what you mean, but as JB Nizet illustrates, synchronisation issue are not easy to spot as it depends on many factors, like CPU usage. You may be lucky and run your program dozens of times without interferences or it could fail on each run

Comment: Your two threads are going to spend a _lot_ more time calling `System.out.printf(...)` than they will spend executing `N++`. To continue JB's analogy, It's like the street that you're crossing with closed eyes is a back alley that hardly anybody ever uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.out.printf` is `synchronized` internally,  though it does not gurantee a failed test, it might have influences.

You can try remove them to eliminate interference, like:

```
private static void incAndPrint() throws InterruptedException {  
    N++; 
}
```

And this passed the test for some time on my computer:

```
final count: 1902
final count: 1111
final count: 1883
```

Comment: After remove both `printf()` on my pc the test passes every single time. Still, I got a intuition that this might has something to do with compiler or JIT optimization. Maybe not just the chance is small, the change could be 0. e.g It might merged the 2 instance lock by `printf()` together with the `N++` between, into a single instance synchronized block, instead of acquiring the lock twice. That's only my guess.